# Images for Area51 proposal community promotion on imgur.com?

Tags: bug, area-51, imgur, community-promotion-ads

For each proposal on Area51, a promotional image is automatically generated and it shows the current state, e.g. number of followers/supporters or comitted. Example:

[image: Example promotion ad]

They’re obviously useful for [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) on existing sites. Alas, the current requirements for those say that the image needs to be hosted on `imgur.com`. I can easily provide the URL `https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/{proposal-number}.png` in the image upload dialog, to get a cryptic `imgur` address back, but I’m afraid that **it won’t update dynamically**.

Please note that I was able to use the `area51` URL on some sites until right now, when the poster generator seems to be broken or off-line, but on other sites the software stopped me from posting any image not hosted on `imgur`. Can we please have the dynamic posters working everywhere (and in “HiDPI”) or be assured that the external service will update them regularly?

Answer (score 9):

You can circumvent the requirements check by making an edit to your post. The system only checks when you first post, not when you edit. Post a false ad linking to an imgur image, then edit it to re-link to the Area 51 promotion image.

[Here's an example](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2940/8708), you can see that it works by checking [the stats](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2881).

---

<sup><sup>Dear devs, please ignore this hack and don't fix it</sup></sup>

Answer (score 1):

We already run proposal ads in the sidebar ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amtrk.png)), so there's no need to spend a community ad slot on that. (Although, granted, they're not particularly targeted or necessarily relevant.)

But if you feel that you want a proposal ad to run more frequently or demo a specific proposal... making your own ad is your best bet at that point IMO.

Comment: So does it mean this is [tag:status-declined]?