# Allow images from Area 51 as Community Ads

Tags: feature-request, area-51, images, community-promotion-ads

I was on Meta Super User trying to submit an ad for the Internet of Things Q&A proposal, with the following in my answer box:

```
[![Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Internet of Things][1]][2]

  [1]: http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/94224.png
  [2]: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/
```

I then got an error:

[image: Error]

> Community ads must have an image hosted at i.stack.imgur.com; use the image button from the editor to upload.

Can we enable Area 51 images for Community Ads?

Comment: Apparently you can't tag your meta post with [tag:community-ads].

Comment: See [Images for Area51 proposal community promotion on imgur.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278436/images-for-area51-proposal-community-promotion-on-imgur-com)

Comment: @Peanut of course, because it's a moderator only tag. But we do have a specific tag for those ads.